# Getting the value of Primefaces' p:editor when onchange is called

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, onchange

I have a  component.
I want to be notified whenever its value is changed. Then I need to check the new value to decide if it's empty (hence, I'll disable the submit button) or not.

The former can be done using the onchange attribute.

My problem is with the latter: accessing p:editor's value from within javascript!

Please help.

Comment: You want to notify the server (AJAX request) or to notify the user (Javascript)??

Comment: @Mindwin User (javascript)

Comment: @SaryAssad Did you try anything ?

Comment: I tried using the onchange attribute and called a javascript function. The function is called successfully. My problem is how to get the text in the p:editor from the jaascript function. I tried passing this from the onchange attribute to the JS function but couldn't get anything useful from the passed object. I'll edit my question and add code snippets.

Comment: Ok I've just found the solution. I'll post it as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Here is the p:editor with the onchange attribute:

`<p:editor onchange="handleTextChange()" id="responseEditor"/>`

and here is the Javascript callback function:

```
function handleTextChange()
{
    editorText = document.getElementById("appDetailsForm:responseEditor_input").value;
    alert(editorText);
}
```

p.s.1 `appDetailsForm` is the id of the enclosing form. Primefaces prepends it to the component's primfaces Id when it generate the html.

p.s.2 `appDetailsForm:responseEditor_input` is the id of the textarea inside the `<p:editor>` component that is created when the html is generated.

Comment: Hi Sary. how could I send the value to the bean? I want to update bean value of the editor...